# Asp.net Core Value from Selected Item in the SelectBox is 0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

So I have managed to populate a select box using `SelectList(...)` and `ViewData[...]`. The items show up in the select box and I can select an item. The *text* for the select box is the category `Name` and the *Value* is the `MenuCategoryID`. I then save the value linked to the text in the `MenuCategoryId` *property* in the model. The issue is that when the user selects an item it seems to save the value as 0, it then passes that in the model to the post request in the controller. Every other value in the model is fine and correct, it is just the value retrieved from the select box.

This is my GET Request:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    List<MenuCategoryViewModel> Categories = await _Context.MenuCategories.ToListAsync();
    ViewData["Categories"] = new SelectList(Categories, "MenuCategoryId", "Name");

    return View();
}
```

This is my SelectBox:

```
<select asp-for="MenuCategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories"></select>
```

This is my `MenuCategoryId` property:

```
[Required]
public int MenuCategoryId { get; set; }
```

This is my POST request:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("MenuItemId,Name,Description,MenuCategoryID")] MenuItemViewModel menuItem)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _Context.Add(menuItem);
        await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(menuItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code, i changed this part of code in the Create Method:

[Bind("MenuItemId,Name,Description,MenuCategoryID")

For:

[Bind("MenuItemId,Name,Description,**MenuCategoryId**")

**MenuCategoryId** equals to property in the MenuItemViewModel class.

It works fine.